# How to make div appear from the top when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like a `div` to appear and slide down once you scroll pass the header.

Here's what it should look like:

http://www.space.com/11425-photos-supernovas-star-explosions.html

Here's what I got so far but it's not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/nHnrd/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to find out the height of the header and its position on the page then just show or hide the div depending on the scrollTop value using jquery.

For example:

```
// Get the headers position from the top of the page, plus its own height
var startY = $('header').position().top + $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkY();
});

function checkY(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
        $('.fixedDiv').slideDown();
    }else{
        $('.fixedDiv').slideUp();
    }
}

// Do this on load just in case the user starts half way down the page
checkY();
```

Then you'll just need to set the .fixedDiv to position:fixed: top: 0; left: 0;

**Edit:** I've added a checkY() function that you can call whenever the page loads as well as on scroll. To hide it initially though, just use CSS.

Comment: sorry just one quick thing.. how do I stop it from displaying at the start? here's my file: http://jsfiddle.net/nHnrd/14/

Comment: @will Is this possible with JavaScript not jQuery

Comment: Yes, definitely, jQuery is just a javascript library after all, but I know what you mean. It's just a little bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to just show and hide your div rather than pseudo class AND hide and show

initially:
 $("#mydiv").hide();
then (on scroll):
 $("#mydiv").show();

set what you want your div to look like i.e. 0,0 and fixed

Use the Keep It Simple method!

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your jsfiddle with something you can try.

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/nHnrd/10/

Also, this article was helpful:
http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/keep-element-in-view-while-scrolling-using-jquery/