# Making Nav Div Appear When Scrolling Down

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I want a div to appear at the top when user scroll down pass a div class called `.header1` (This div has 3 other div inside)

I want the nav to appear in that `.fixedDiv`. I found my answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905670/how-to-make-div-appear-from-the-top-when-scrolling-down)**, but I have not been able to implement it on my site. 
Here is what I got

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var startY = $('.header1').position().top + $('.header1').outerHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > startY ){
            $('.fixedDiv').slideDown();
        }else{
            $('.fixedDiv').slideUp();
        }
    });
</script>
```

And I have a div called `.fixedDiv` on my site saying topnav, my problem is the div is always there. It doesn't hide or appear when scrolling down.

[This](http://www.ehowtodrywall.com) is a link to my website.

For css I have nothing setup for `.header1` because other div are inside and they should be the height needed for `.fixedDiv` to appear. And `.fixedDiv` has css

```css
.fixedDiv {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:orange;
}
```

I know I'm close to getting this working but I just can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally got it figured out, and I love it, it looks great

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var startY= jQuery('.header1').position().top + jQuery('.header1').outerHeight();
jQuery('.fixedDiv').html( jQuery('#nav').html());
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > startY ){
        jQuery('.fixedDiv').slideDown();
    }else{
        jQuery('.fixedDiv').slideUp();
    }
});
});
```

Not sure what the extra line (line 3) does but that what was missing ...
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Testing `$(".header1").position()` gives `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

You appear to be in [noConflict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document) due to WordPress.

Try this instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var startY= $('.header1').position().top + $('.header1').outerHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > startY ){
            $('.fixedDiv').slideDown();
        }else{
            $('.fixedDiv').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Edit:** you have an extra `<script>` tag (at least, Chrome sees it). It appears to work fine in Firefox.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to change wordpress mode maybe ?

Comment: @PhilippeAllaire You're missing a `.top` on your website. (It's `startY=jQuery(".header1").position().top + ...`) You also need to change all the other `$`s below that line to `jQuery`.

Comment: @PhilippeAllaire You can use the `(function($){ ...` code in my answer to treat `$` as `jQuery`.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, I have change all the $ into jQuery and I have added the .top , but it's still not working for me :(

Comment: @PhilippeAllaire Your website still doesn't have a `.top` or `jQuery`s in place of `$`.

Comment: I have cleared the cache for you, sorry but as admin I don't get the cache files ...

Comment: @PhilippeAllaire You appear to have an extra `<script>` tag above the code.

Comment: I found an extra </script> tag below the code ? but again this had no effect :( Last guy said jQuery not loaded on site ? Is this tru ? I did not find extra <script> tag above code ...

Comment: @PhilippeAllaire There shouldn't be an extra `</script>`, but an extra `<script type="text/javascript">`. And jQuery should be loaded...

Comment: I have searched the header.php file and I cannot find an extra <script> tag above .... anyway to be more specific on location ?

Comment: @PhilippeAllaire Right above `var startY= jQuery(".header1").position().top + ...` - see updated answer

Comment: I'm sorry but I have examine page source from firefox and there is only one <script> tag above

Comment: @PhilippeAllaire Oh, Firefox appears to parse it just fine. Try my updated answer.

Comment: .... I am having no luck with this issue :( I have implemented the updated code from above with no effect still .... frustrating lol

Comment: @PhilippeAllaire Try it without the `$`s and with the `jQuery`s. and take out the `$` in `function($)`.

Comment: Done, but still not working ... I;m sure your a buzy man and I don't want to bother you to much, so I'm going to hire someone from fiverr and see if they can maybe fix it, I will update this thread if they can figure it out ... Unless you have a better idea ...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a fadeIn and fadeOut with setInterval on scroll?  Something along the lines of...

```
.scroll( function()
{
    if($(".fixedDiv").css('display', 'none'))
    {
        $(".fixedDiv").fadeIn("normal", function()
        {
            setInterval( function() { $(".fixedDiv").fadeOut("normal"); }, 1500 );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: From my understanding if your wordpress is in nonconflict mode than you could use jQuery(selector) instead of $(selector).